# Public "in a relationship" Facebook status without news feeding?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I changed my relationship status a few weeks ago from "single" to "in a relationship" (leaving the person-in-question box empty). Today I want this info as-is to be publicly accessible on my profile, but not have it plastered on other people's news feeds. How do I accomplish this?

Will it suffice to change the "only me" privacy setting to "public"?

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Do you have privacy setting for this as "only me"? If yes, change it with "public" or "friends" to show it on your friends timeline.

Comment: @serenesat I don't want it on my timeline (or any of my friend's). Neither on anyone's newsfeed. No snooping aunts and uncles. No big "event". Just available under my "about" section as a confirmation for inquiring friends.

Comment: Then use custom settings and exclude all whom you don't want see this.

Comment: @serenesat I have mis-phrased my needs a bit. Everyone must be able to see this under "about"->"relationships". But I don't want it on my timeline (this is easy), and (this is the important part) I don't want it to be pushed to other people's news feeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change any activity, and don't want it to appear in friends News Feed, keep the audience "Only Me", After sometime (around 24-hrs) change the audience to "Public" or "Friends" or any custom. It will not appear to anyone's Timeline, but whenever someone visit your profile they will be able to see latest update.

So, yes, it will suffice to change the "Only Me" privacy setting to "Public".